# Find and transfrer mysql database to another computer

Tags: mysql, database, file-transfer

i'm using myaql database for my website which is in my computer.

I'm trying to transfer the database to another computer but I can't find any mysql database file...

My question is if it is possible and how can I do it? (Is there any simple way?)

Comment: are you talking about a website that you have locally hosted on your computer using xampp or wampp or something of that sort?

Comment: Yes the website hosted in my computer, I have no idea if it is in xampp or wampp (how can I check it?)

Answer (score 0):

[MYSQL DUMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

**It can be used to dump a database or a collection of databases for backup or transfer to another SQL server (not necessarily a MySQL server).**